# Subtraction of numbers with arbitrary bases

Tags: recreational-mathematics, online-resources, calculator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do +, -, *, / with number in a base b?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/how-to-do-with-number-in-a-base-b)

I am reading research papers in the category of recreational mathematics on the topic of numbers similar to [Kaprekar number](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Kaprekar_number). Almost all the time we come across subtration of numbers with arbritrary bases such as 11, 13, 8 etc..

Can someone please explain me as to how this kind of calculation is to be done? Is there any free calculator/software available on net that does this kind of calculation?

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65363/calculator-for-arithmetic-in-alternate-bases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us subtract `313663` from `403155` in base 11.  Digits in base 11 are `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,**`A`**.  In base 11, instead of writing 10 + 1 = 11, we write `A` + `1` = `10`.  And instead of writing 10 + 10 = 20, we write `A` + `A` = `19`. I will write base-11 numerals in this special font with the gray background, so that they are easy to recognize.

```
    4  0  3  1  5  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
```

Let's call the columns, in order from right to left, columns $C_0, C_1,\ldots C_5$.  The algorithm is the same as in base 10, except that we use 11 instead of 10.  We start in column $C_0$. `5`-`3` is `2`:

```
    4  0  3  1  5  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
                   2
```

In column $C_1$, we have `5`-`6`, which is negative, so we borrow an 11 from the `1` in column $C_2$ and change the `5` to a `15`.

```
    4  0  3  0 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
                   2
```

Note that the `15` in column $C_1$ is not the base-ten 15; it is the base-eleven `15`, which is base-ten 16. `15`-`6` = `A`.

```
    4  0  3  0 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
                A  2
```

Now we can't take `6` from `0`, so we borrow an 11 from the `3` in the $C_3$ column:

```
    4  0  2 10 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
                A  2
```

`10`-`6` = `5`:

```
    4  0  2 10 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
             5  A  2
```

Now in column $C_3$ we have `2`-`3`, so we sould like to borrow from $C_4$, but $C_4$ has a `0`, so there is nothing to borrow.  So instead we borrow 11 from $C_5$ to $C_4$:

```
    3 10  2 10 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
             5  A  2
```

And then we can borrow from $C_4$ to $C_3$:

```
    3  A 12 10 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
             5  A  2
```

Now in column $C_3$ we have `12`-`3` = `A`, and in column $C_4$ we have `A`-`1`=`9`:

```
    3  A 12 10 15  5
-   3  1  3  6  6  3
--------------------
       9  A  5  A  2
```

And finally in column $C_5$ we have `3`-`3` = `0`, so we are done, and the answer is `403155` - `313663` = `9A5A2`.

Comment: so it's basically the same thing? Nothing complicated as I was imagining?

Comment: It's just the same. There is nothing special about 10.